# How to manage text labels in a simple interactive matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, interactive, mouse-picking

In this code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def onclick(event):
  plt.text(event.xdata, event.ydata, f'x', color='black')
  plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
data = np.random.rand(8, 8)
plt.imshow(data, origin='lower', interpolation='None', aspect='equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

each mouse click leaves an additional letter `x` on top of the image:

[image]

I would like to have only the most recent `x` shown. How to accomplish it, while keeping it simple?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you declare a global variable called "txt" or something, and then on click you would first remove the "current" x and add the new one.

```
txt = None

def onclick(event):
    global txt
    if txt:
        txt.remove()
    txt = plt.text(event.xdata, event.ydata, 'TESTTEST', fontsize=8)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Something like this. It may be messy, But try it.

Comment: Thanks. It works after a correction: `if txt: txt.remove()`. The first `fig.canvas.draw()` is not necessary.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Nice, Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Do you know, by the chance, how to remove all text added to the plot with one matplotlib function call? What is the data structure holding references to the text?

Comment: @PaulJurczak If I remember correctly doing `plot.texts` should return a List or Tuple of all texts on the plot.

Answer (score 0):

The text objects are stored internally by matplotlib. The ones created by `plt.text()` can be removed. Here is the original code snippet, modified to accomplish this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as text
import numpy as np

def onclick(event):
  for x in plt.findobj(match=text.Text):
    try:
      x.remove()
    except NotImplementedError:
      pass

  plt.text(event.xdata, event.ydata, f'x', color='black')
  plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
data = np.random.rand(8, 8)
plt.imshow(data, origin='lower', interpolation='None', aspect='equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```